# Binding an event to an item in jsGRid not working after first page

Tags: jquery, jsgrid

I created a Grid using `jsGrid` library. the code is pasted below. On click of the image, the user should navigate to another page

```
function fillpatientsGrid(){

    $("#patientsgrid").jsGrid({
        width: "90%",
        height: "600px" ,      
        sorting: true,
        paging: true,
        pageSize: 12,
        data: patientsData,
        controller: {
            loadData: function(filter) {
                console.log("loadData");
            },
        },
        fields: [
            { name: "name", title:"Name",type: "text",readOnly: true,align:"center",width: 120 },
            { name: "DOB",title:"DOB",type: "text",align:"center", width: 70, sorter: function(date1, date2) {
                return new Date(date1) - new Date(date2);
              }},
            { name: "Gender", title:"Gender",type: "text", align:"center",width: 70},
            { name: "Age",title:"Age", type: "number", align:"center", width: 70} ,  
            { name: "LastReportedByDate", title:"Last Visit",type: "text",align:"center", width: 70},
            { name: "createdBy", title:"Created By",type: "text",align:"center", width: 70},
            { name: "uuid", title:"Patient Record",type: "text",align:"center", width: 100,itemTemplate: function(value, item) {
                    return '<img src="/images/patient-record.png" class="recordimage" "width="30" height="30" uuid='+value+'>';
             }}         
        ]

    });

    $(".recordimage").on('click',function(){
        
        var uuid=$(this).attr('uuid');
        window.location.href = '/patientrecord/?useruuid='+uuid;
      
    })
}
```

I am showing 12 records on each page. But the issue is that after the first page, recordimage click does not works. Let me know how this can be resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) Click event code needs to be outside of the function.

b) Since the image loaded on each page so use [Event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

```
function fillpatientsGrid(){

    $("#patientsgrid").jsGrid({
        width: "90%",
        height: "600px" ,      
        sorting: true,
        paging: true,
        pageSize: 12,
        data: patientsData,
        controller: {
            loadData: function(filter) {
                console.log("loadData");
            },
        },
        fields: [
            { name: "name", title:"Name",type: "text",readOnly: true,align:"center",width: 120 },
            { name: "DOB",title:"DOB",type: "text",align:"center", width: 70, sorter: function(date1, date2) {
                return new Date(date1) - new Date(date2);
              }},
            { name: "Gender", title:"Gender",type: "text", align:"center",width: 70},
            { name: "Age",title:"Age", type: "number", align:"center", width: 70} ,  
            { name: "LastReportedByDate", title:"Last Visit",type: "text",align:"center", width: 70},
            { name: "createdBy", title:"Created By",type: "text",align:"center", width: 70},
            { name: "uuid", title:"Patient Record",type: "text",align:"center", width: 100,itemTemplate: function(value, item) {
                    return '<img src="/images/patient-record.png" class="recordimage" "width="30" height="30" uuid='+value+'>';
             }}         
        ]

    });
}

$(document).on("click",".recordimage",function(){
    var uuid=$(this).attr('uuid');
    window.location.href = '/patientrecord/?useruuid='+uuid;
  
})
```

Comment: This works but I also found one more solution . Will post it tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

Attaching a click event to the image by using the itemtemplate also works . Check out my code below

```
function fillpatientsGrid(){ 
      
    $("#patientsgrid").jsGrid({
        width: "90%",
        height: "600px" ,      
        sorting: true,
        paging: true,
        pageSize: 12,         
        data: patientsData,  
        controller: {
            loadData: function(filter) {
                console.log("loadData");                   
            },             
             
        }, 
       

        fields: [
            { name: "name", title:"Name",type: "text",readOnly: true,align:"center",width: 120 },
            { name: "DOB",title:"DOB",type: "text",align:"center", width: 70, sorter: function(date1, date2) {
                return new Date(date1) - new Date(date2);
              }},
            { name: "Gender", title:"Gender",type: "text", align:"center",width: 70},
            { name: "Age",title:"Age", type: "number", align:"center", width: 70} ,  
            { name: "LastReportedByDate", title:"Last Visit",type: "text",align:"center", width: 70},
            { name: "createdBy", title:"Created By",type: "text",align:"center", width: 70},
            { name: "uuid", title:"Patient Record",type: "text",align:"center", width: 100,itemTemplate: function(value, item) {
                   
                var $customImage= $('<img src="/images/patient-record.png" class="recordimage" "width="30" height="30" uuid='+value+'>')
                                .click(function () {
                                    window.location.href = '/patientrecord/?useruuid='+value;
                                    
                                });
                            
                    return $customImage;
                
                
             }}         
           
        ]

       

    });

   
             



}
```